# std::is_signed does not work for strongly typed enums : int

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Can anyone please explain, why

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
enum E : signed int { a=-1, b = 1,};
int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << "strong typed enum E:int should be signed, but is_signed returns " 
    << is_signed<E>() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

`std::is_signed<>` does not do, what it says on the tin?

Comment: Use `is_signed<underlying_type<E>::type>()` instead

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks a lot for the proper solution of my problem (that should not be any problem, if the C++ standard would be more intuitive in this case...)

Comment: Use std::underlying_type_t<E> please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for [is_signed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) it says:

> If **T is a signed arithmetic type**, provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

and an enum is not an arithmetic type so the result should be false. From the draft C++11 standard section `3.9.1` Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]:

> [...]Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic
>   types[...]

You can get the underlying type for an enum using [std::underlying_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) and then apply `std::is_signed` to that type.

Comment: @xy That's a matter of opinion, really. I myself would be *extremely* surprised if an enumeration type reported as signed.

Comment: @Angew - I agree - if it would be a "usual" enum, but the notation of strongly typed enums with the **: int**  thingy  is so misleading to think of simple derivation from int.

Comment: @xy Again, I view it the other way round - for me, a strongly typed enum is even further away from arithmetic types than a "usual" one, lacking implicit conversions and all.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, to know whether the *underlying type* of a strongly typed enum (that is, not the enum itself, which [can't be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33364183/3953764) checked for signedness) is signed or not, you can query [`std::underlying_type<E>::type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type):

```
std::is_signed<std::underlying_type<E>::type>::value
```

or define your own trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
struct is_signed
    : std::is_signed<typename std::conditional<std::is_enum<T>::value
                                             , std::underlying_type<T>
                                             , identity<T>>::type::type> {};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4b22ec5e44addc1)

Comment: I tried to fix the issue, but could't make it that far... Can you please give me an idea, what's wrong with


#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
struct resolve_type
{
    using resolved_type = typename conditional<is_enum<T>::value, underlying_type<T>, typename T>::type;
};
enum E : int { a = -1, b = 1, };
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << "is_signed enum E = " << is_signed<resolve_type<E>::resolved_type>::value << " <=> true\n";
    return 0;
}

Comment: @xy it should be `using resolved_type = typename conditional<is_enum<T>::value, underlying_type<T>, T>::type;`, you have a redundant `typename` keyword

Comment: Nope, in VC++2013 it still says, my enum's underlying type is not signed.

Comment: @ PiotrSkotnicki Ok, now I've got it - the correct (but somehow weird) template to handle **is_signed<>** with simple types **and** enums is:

template<typename T>
struct resolve_type
{
    using resolved_type = typename conditional<is_enum<T>::value, underlying_type<T>, T>::type::type;
};

You are a good man... thanks

Comment: Piotr, your extension of the **is_signed** template above is, how it really should be. So I suggested it to the C++ standard comitee - naming you as creator of course...

Comment: Though a very useful template, I really don't think the committee should, or will, backtrack on this simply because you didn't read all the way through what they'd written the first time around.