# Is it possible to determine if a parameter of a function is signed or unsigned for a possibility overloaded function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

There are ways to determine if a function exists, and there are ways to determine if a function has a particular signature.  But is there a way to determine if it has a signature that contains a signed or unsigned parameter while the name may be *overloaded*?

## Example

```
struct A {
 void fn(int) {}
};

struct B {
 void fn(unsigned) {}
};

struct C {
 void fn(int) {}
 void fn(unsigned) {}
};
```

The closest I could think that this would be possible is if I tested specifically for every signed type, and then if not found, every unsigned type.  That will however, exclude any enum type or new type in the future.

Comment: You could test if `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is equal to zero, i.e. `if(!std::numeric_limits<T>::min()){ /* is unsigned */ }`.

Comment: @Bernard: Exactly how do you propose to get `T`?

Comment: @MSalters Oops sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it, works for free functions as well as member functions.  There is a type trait in the standard library that checks for `unsigned`-ness [`std::is_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned)

---

After reading the answer below, a slight update to my answer.  Here is how I would check to see if the type list has any unsigned data type.

The usual way I go about checking for a condition on a list of types is similar to the way it is done int he standard library.  I wrote a small trait that helps you generalize this.  See `AnyOf` below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <template <typename...> class Predicate, typename TypeList>
struct AnyOf {
    static constexpr const bool value = false;
};
template <template <typename...> class Predicate,
          typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct AnyOf<Predicate, std::tuple<Head, Tail...>> {
    static constexpr const bool value
        = Predicate<Head>::value
            || AnyOf<Predicate, std::tuple<Tail...>>::value;
};

void foo(int) {}
void bar(unsigned) {}
struct Something {
    void foo(int);
    void bar(unsigned);
};

namespace detail {
    template <typename Func>
    struct IsFirstUnsignedImpl;
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    struct IsFirstUnsignedImpl<ReturnType (*) (Args...)> {
        constexpr static const bool value
            = AnyOf<std::is_unsigned, std::tuple<Args...>>::value;
    };
    template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    struct IsFirstUnsignedImpl<ReturnType (ClassType::*) (Args...)> {
        constexpr static const bool value
            = AnyOf<std::is_unsigned, std::tuple<Args...>>::value;
    };
} // namespace detail

template <typename Func>
struct IsFirstUnsigned {
    constexpr static bool value
        = detail::IsFirstUnsignedImpl<std::decay_t<Func>>::value;
};

int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha << IsFirstUnsigned<decltype(foo)>::value << endl;
    cout << std::boolalpha << IsFirstUnsigned<decltype(bar)>::value << endl;
    cout << std::boolalpha << IsFirstUnsigned<decltype(&Something::foo)>::value
         << endl;
    cout << std::boolalpha << IsFirstUnsigned<decltype(&Something::bar)>::value
         << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd also template on the return type.  Otherwise you are restricted to functions which return nothing (i.e. `void`).

Comment: @Curious Don't forget to mention that if you take a pointer to member function this way, you might need to add overload for all possible qualifier combinations , something that look [just like that](https://github.com/gracicot/kangaru/blob/master/include/kangaru/detail/function_traits.hpp#L36)

Comment: But does not [handle enums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33363994/1708801)

Comment: This doesn't look like it'll handle overloads

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have a solution for that, but it doesn't handle the case where the function is overloaded with different unsigned types.

```
template<typename T>
struct has_fn {
private:
    struct to_unsigned {
        template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<U>::value>* = nullptr>
        operator U () const;
    };

    template<typename U, void_t<decltype(std::declval<U>().fn(to_unsigned{}))>* = nullptr>
    static std::true_type test(int);

    template<typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    constexpr static bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};
```

You can use it like that:

```
int main() {
    struct A {
        void fn(int) {}
    };

    struct B {
        void fn(unsigned) {}
    };

    struct C {
        void fn(int) {}
        void fn(unsigned) {}
    };

    static_assert(!has_fn<A>::value, "");
    static_assert(has_fn<B>::value, "");
    static_assert(has_fn<C>::value, "");
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/579c35dbf16ab784)</kbd>

If you don't have C++17, you can implement `void_t` like this:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution checks if there is *any* unsigned type in the parameter list.  This does not (and cannot) work for overloaded functions, because overload resolution depends on the caller.  Here we are only examining the function itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename >
struct has_unsigned_param : std::false_type {};

template < typename R, typename T >
struct has_unsigned_param < R(T) >
{
  static constexpr bool value = std::is_unsigned < T >::value;
};

template < typename R, typename T, typename ... S >
struct has_unsigned_param < R(T,S...) >
{
  static constexpr bool value =
    std::is_unsigned < T >::value || has_unsigned_param < R(S...) >::value;
};

template < typename C, typename R, typename ... T >
struct has_unsigned_param < R(C::*)(T...) >
{
  static constexpr bool value = has_unsigned_param < R(T...) >::value;
};

struct foo {
  void test1(int) {}
  void test2(unsigned int) {}
  void test3(int, unsigned int) {}
  void test4(int, unsigned int, double) {}
  void test5(int, unsigned int, float, unsigned char) {}
  void test6(int, int, float, char) {}
};

void test1(int) {}
void test2(unsigned int) {}
void test3(int, unsigned int) {}
void test4(int, unsigned int, double) {}
void test5(int, unsigned int, float, unsigned char) {}
void test6(int, int, float, char) {}

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(test1) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(test2) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(test3) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(test4) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(test5) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(test6) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(&foo::test1) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(&foo::test2) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(&foo::test3) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(&foo::test4) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(&foo::test5) >::value << '\n';
  std::cout << has_unsigned_param < decltype(&foo::test6) >::value << '\n';
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://ideone.com/VO2biS)</kbd>

Comment: So the answer is no then? That was my understanding as well. I just wanted to make sure. Although this contains the answer, it also contains a lot of other stuff detracting from it.